# Prevent varnish from caching cookie response

Tags: varnish

When varnish returns a cache, does it also return the cookie generated on the backend or only the css, images and html returned to the frontend? I had users tell me that they kept getting the wrong cookies, so I am thinking because the cookies are based on geolocation data that the reason was the varnish cache. If it is so, is there a way to prevent varnish to return any cached data for cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish's built-in VCL behavior will send `Set-Cookie` headers that were send by the origin server to the client. This will allow the client to have the appropriate cookie set in the browser.

However, because a `Set-Cookie` header implies a state change, Varnish will not store these results in cache and will return a so-called *Hit-For-Miss* object for the next 2 minutes.

This means that the next request for that object will automatically bypass the cache. If any of the subsequent backend responses no longer contain the `Set-Cookie` header, Varnish will consider the response to be cacheable.

See https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/6.0/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl#L157-L165 for the built-in VCL that defines this behavior.

> Unless your VCL actively intervenes with logic in the `vcl_backend_response` subroutine, the default behavior will always be in effect and responses containing `Set-Cookie` headers will not be cached.

Please share your VCL to see whether or not this is the case.